# Dynamodb: hot spot and data model

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I need some advice about the design my tables so that certain queries are possible. My main table has the following user information:

`id | gender | location | fullDOB | yearDOB | name`.

I need to be able to answer questions like: give a list of users between ages 25-35 who are males/females within 50 miles. Most likely, in the future I will want to add more attributes that I'll filter on.  I'm not worried about figuring out location part at the moment, I want to start off with age and gender. I have created field yearD0B so I can query based on users age. To do this I wanted to create GSI on yearDOB along with other attributes I'll filter on so the GSI would look like follows:

`yearDOB(pk) | id (sort key) | gender | location`

Then I could issue Query and filter on the rest of the attributes. However, if I use yearDOB then e.g. 10,000 users could have the same birthyear which will create a hot spot. One way to solve this is to append a random number but it would have to be within a very large range to avoid hot spot. This would create a headache trying to query all users with a certain age if this number is huge.

Questions:

1) Is my approach of creating a GSI on filter attributes good in terms of having to support the above types of queries ?

2) If it's good how do I efficently solve the problem of a hot partition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I realized that DynamoDb just isn't suited to perform those types of queries. Even if I was to avoid hot spots somehow, then if a user wanted to change their birthyear, it would not be possible as primary keys in GSI cannot be updated. Simple queries in dynamo are not possible without significant jigerry pokery, it doesn't live up to all the hype. Back to RDS, pity ...

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB now supports adaptive capacity. So you dont have to worry about hot spotting.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive